# Android Programming and Java syntax

Tags: java

This is a question regarding the syntax used in Eclipse SDK while programming some JAVA code for an Android App.

I am an embedded microcontroller engineer that's mainly used to programming in Assembler (a long time ago) and C. I am a newbie when it comes C++ and JAVA and to help me write my code I have been using a mix of the developer.android.com for background info and stackoverflow.com for real world examples and have found them very useful.

So, I have no problem writing code to do what I want to do because I've always done it, but I am finding it very difficult getting my head around the syntax used in writing Android Apps.

For example to access the GPS one of my lines of code read thus:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

but can be shortened to this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

I prefer the second version, but why were some examples written like the first example? Both seem to work fine. I've seen other examples that look even more complicated using "Class".

Secondly, is this not a complicated way to do a really simple thing:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Hello World",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Why not:

```
Toast("Hello world");
```

It now takes me four times as long as it use to write code.

Comment: So... Do you have a question about a problem or are you just seeking approval for your own code style? Frameworks tend to expose all functionality in a regular way first, optimize for common use cases later – if at all. It's perfectly alright to create your own utilities to make it simpler to access the things you need often.

Comment: No, he's not understanding what Java code style and such are about.

Comment: @CharlieMartin Either way, I don't think "Someone defend someone else's API design decisions" is an appropriate SO question.

Comment: Were that his question I suppose you'd have a point.  Since he's a Java beginner with other experience, I'd read it instead as a real request for real informatin.

Answer (score 0):

The line break after the cast there is just to keep the lines from getting too long.

On this:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Hello World",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

... it *would* be simple to write it as you say, aexcept that doesn't do the same things.  Basically, that line is

1. Finding the outermost enclosing place to put graphics
2. Setting the text you want to show, and setting some formatting or some such
3. and then showing it.

You want to split those up because you don't always write to the outermost world, and you may want to, for example, make several different chunks of text and `show90` or `hide()` them later.  (Think an error message and a success message, for example.  You like to build them once and then show/hide the ones you don't need.)

Now, if you can define what context you want and never want to mess with the visibillty, you can make a function that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is kind of beginner OOP-ish style to put `this` everywhere. It is implied in your second example, and the second example is the more common style.
2. Now this one has to do with a bit of engineering. Yes, your second short example could have been implemented (except that `Toast` is a class, not a function, but a similar thing would work), but it would preclude a lot of important things you may want to do. A `Toast` may not be all that lightweight of an object; you may want to cache it. That's why you first get an instance with `makeText` and only then call `show` on it. The `Toast` instance will also have a complete lifecycle that you need to control, but won't be able to with your simple example. The instance can probably undergo further configuration, etc. etc. In short, there's a reason for it which is not obvious from a *Hello, world* piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Android and Java programming. Since you come from an assembly language background, my advice is: Get used to more typing. :)

Regarding the first code fragment: First, the qualifier `this.` on the call to `getSystemService()` is redundant; you can just drop it. Secondly, you can eliminate the qualifier on `LOCATION_SERVICE` by statically importing the name. Add something like this to the imports for the compilation unit:

```
import static android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
```

or, if you don't mind the namespace pollution:

```
import static android.content.Context.*;
```

Regarding the second fragment: for architectural reasons, `Toast` eventually needs to associate the popup window to some application context. The first argument to the factory method `makeToast` is what makes this possible. (By the way, you just need `getContext()`, not `getBaseContext()`. You could also stash the context in a field.) As far as the third argument to `makeText`—arguably, a version of the factory method could have been provided that has a default display time, but Android doesn't provide that, so you're stuck with the third argument as well. You can again avoid the qualifier by statically importing `LENGTH_SHORT`. Finally, the factory method just returns a `Toast` object. You aren't required to `show()` it just yet; it could be stashed and shown at a future time. It's good design to separate creating the `Toast` object from the action of putting it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**I will try to explain the things in the easiest way and to the best of my ability.**

**1.** "`.this`" refers to the **current object** in Java. "`.this`" specifically points to the current object accessing its own instance variable members of that class.

**2.** Using "this" is just being more specific.

**3.** Now in the case of Toast, It requires the "`context`" parameter to point to the Activity
       where it will display the Toast.(ie on which activity)

**4.** You can use "this" if you are not inside an Anonymous class, or if you are in an Anonymouse class then use "`Your_Activity_Name.this`" in place of context.

**5.** `getBaseContext, getApplicationContext` are like global access to the parts of the Application.

**6.** I always prefer `Your_Activity_Name.this` in context place. Context means the Activity, on which the Toast is going to be displayed. And yes there is **No** `Toast(String s)` method in activity.